# Nand this Boolean Algebra Function?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm trying to convert this Expression that I got from minterms given to me by my professor to use only NANDS. I swear it should be right, but the output Multisim is giving me is false.

minterms(0,1,2,3,4,5,7,14,15)

Expression: ~A~B + ~A~C + ABC + ~AD

So, converted to NANDs, it should be: ~AB nand ~AC nand ABC nand ~AD, right?

Comment: What does NANDing some expression mean? Does it mean you write it only in terms of NADN, or compute the NAND of it with itself?

Comment: My assignment is to implement the function using only NAND Gates. So I have to convert the expression to use only NANDs. Sorry that wasn't clear, I've updated the OP with better language.

Comment: Is "Multisim" a simulator for logical circuits?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If I am given a expression to convert it so that there is only NAND inside, I use the fact that AND, OR, and NOT gates can be expressed in NANDs only, and if needed use de Morgan rule.

e.g.

a AND b = NOT (NOT( a AND b)) = NOT (a NAND  b)= True NAND (a NAND b)